# how to create columns for each element given a column of lists pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data look like this:

[image]

The column 'omega' contains lists of 12 numerical values. What's the fastest implementation to create a column for each of the elements (e.g. 12 columns containing numerical values) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way is to initialise the new *dataframe* with list of values obtained using [`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['omega'].tolist())
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'omega': [np.arange(12).tolist()]* 5})
print(df)
                                    omega
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
3  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
4  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['omega'].tolist()).add_prefix('col')
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10  col11
0     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11
1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11
2     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11
3     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11
4     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10     11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'omega': [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]]
})
df = df['omega'].apply(pd.Series)
print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5  5
1  1  2  3  4  5  5
2  1  2  3  4  5  5
3  1  2  3  4  5  5
4  1  2  3  4  5  5
```